# Could not load file or assembly: The assembly may have been tampered with, or it was delay signed but not fully signed with the correct private key

Tags: c#, asp.net

I use in my project ASP.NET assemblies building from source code. My project builded successful. But when I start in debug mode, I get exception

Could not load file or assembly 'System.Net.Http.Formatting' or one of its dependencies. Strong name signature could not be verified.  The assembly may have been tampered with, or it was delay signed but not fully signed with the correct private key. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131045)

Comment: `I use in my project ASP.NET assemblies building from source code.` Are you trying to say that you are using assemblies from projects in the solution? All assemblies are built from source code....

Comment: I build ASP.NET solution which  downloaded from http://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com. Then I add references to ASP.NET assemblies in my project and get this error.

Comment: Your **building** Asp.net for your project? Why? Use the release version!

Comment: Release version doesn't contain new features.

Comment: Signed nightly builds: http://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/discussions/353867

Comment: I am getting the same error.  The reason I am using my own compiled sources is that I need to troubleshoot an issue and debug into the sources and I haven't found a place to download pdbs froms.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to get around this issue for my odata dll by removing the following line of code from the project file of the asp web stack odata project.

```
<Import Project="$([MSBuild]::GetDirectoryNameOfFileAbove($(MSBuildThisFileDirectory),Runtime.sln))\tools\WebStack.settings.targets" />
```

Comment: where did you remove this line?

Comment: that line is from the project or solution file.

Answer (score 0):

Try and remove the dll from the bin folder and rebuild your solution. I don't know why but this solved it for me.

Answer (score 0):

Deleting files from Bin and Obj/Debug folder, fixed my problem.